# How to get a few rows that have similar values (not exactly equal) in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe in which there are multiple columns. Let us call the columns as "col1", "col2", etc.

If someone asks: Please give me the rows from the dataframe with df["col1"] values similar to a number x. In this case I want to give a few rows (say 10) where 5 rows have values smaller then x and another 5 have values bigger than x. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Currently, I am doing this:

```
df[(df["col1"]<=x+delta1) & (df["col1"]>=x-delta2)]
```

However, this is inefficient as I have to find the right delta1 and delta2 every time by sorting. Is there a short code to do this, where delta1 and delta2 need not be captured.

Comment: Are the rows sorted?  If so, and you find the value `x`, you can just return from row-5 through row+5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `between` method in pandas:

```
df[df["col1"].between(x-delta2, x+delta1, inclusive = "both")]
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.